# javascript and jquery array each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I cant get this to work. I am trying to replace certain characters when a key is pressed. It works fine when I use the variable replace_list instead of replace_list["russian"], but I need different "replace lists" for other things. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<input id=answer>
<script>
replace_list = ["russian": {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#answer").keydown(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $.each(replace_list["russian"], function (index, value) {
                if (index == text.substring(text.length - value.length)) {
                    $("#answer").val(text.substring(0, text.length - value.length) + value);
               }
           });
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: If you're writing `replace_list[0] = ...` without having first defined `replace_list` that will cause an error. You can fix this by first creating an array - `var replace_list = []` - or by making your assignment an array assignment: `var replace_list = [{ ... }]`. Other than that, your code does not seem to produce any meaningful difference in outcome depending on whether your object is placed at `replace_list` or `replace_list[0]`.

Comment: Your current code looks correct except for the line
["russian": {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}]
which should read
{"russian": {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the array first (or adjust the assignment)

```
var replace_list = [
    {'a' : 'а', 'A' : 'А', 'b' : 'б'},    // replace_list[0]
    {'B' : 'Б', 'v' : 'в', 'V' : 'В'}     // replace_list[1]
]
```

**Edit**
To meet your requirements (`replace_list["russian"]`) from the comment

```
var replace_list = {
    "russian": {'a' : 'а', 'A' : 'А', 'b' : 'б'},
    "english": {'a' : 'а', 'A' : 'A', 'b' : 'B'}
}
```

Comment: Something like that is exactly what i need! But how would I go about making the first entry replace_list["russian"] ?

Comment: make replace_list as an Object...and then try defining each as replace_list["russian"] = {<your definitions>},replace_list["german"]={<another list>}, and so on

Comment: It still doesn't work, I edited my question, try and copy paste the code

Comment: @Stuffle: You've used the wrong brackets. You need the curly brackets `{ }` instead of the square ones `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should properly define `replace_list`; I will assume you're going to have multiple replace lists that you would like to apply in certain situations:

```
var replace_list = {
    'russian': {a: 'b', b: 'c', c: 'd'}
};
```

Then:

```
var text = $(this).val();
for (var search in replace_list['russian']) {
    text = text.replace(search, replace_list['russian'][search]);
}

$('#answer').val(text);
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/k8Dhg/

Comment: yes it is. It transliterates English letters into Russian cyrillic symbols in this example

Comment: I can't get it to work. I really suck at Javascript so I am sure thats why.
Anyway, the function needs to be able to handle replacements that are longer than 1 char. Also I would love if there was a solution that didn't mean I would have to change too much. It just seems strange to me that everything works with replace_list, but not with replace_list[0]...

Comment: Thanks for the help Jack, but what if I needed it to be replace_list["russian"] instead of just replace_list[0]? I know I should have written that in the question, sorry.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just `var replace_list = {"russian": { your replacement list here }}`

Comment: I cant get it to work. I edited my question, try and copy paste the code. I couldnt get it to work with your modifications either :(

Comment: @Stuffe you made a mistake in the initializer; updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var replace_list = new Object();
replace_list["russian"] = {'a' : 'а', 'A' : 'А', 'b' : 'б', 'B' : 'Б', 'v' : 'в', 'V' : 'В', 'g' : 'г', 'G' : 'Г', 'd' : 'д', 'D' : 'Д', 'ye' : 'е', 'YE' : 'Е', 'yo' : 'ё', 'YO' : 'Ё', 'zh' : 'ж', 'ZH' : 'Ж', 'z' : 'з', 'Z' : 'З', 'i' : 'и', 'I' : 'И', 'j' : 'й', 'J' : 'Й', 'k' : 'к', 'K' : 'К', 'l' : 'л', 'L' : 'Л', 'm' : 'м', 'M' : 'М', 'n' : 'н', 'N' : 'Н', 'o' : 'о', 'O' : 'О', 'p' : 'п', 'P' : 'П', 'r' : 'р', 'R' : 'Р', 's' : 'с', 'S' : 'С', 't' : 'т', 'T' : 'Т', 'u' : 'у', 'U' : 'У', 'f' : 'ф', 'F' : 'Ф', 'kh' : 'х', 'KH' : 'Х', 'ts' : 'ц', 'TS' : 'Ц', 'ch' : 'ч', 'CH' : 'Ч', 'sh' : 'ш', 'SH' : 'Ш', 'shch' : 'щ', 'SHCH' : 'Щ', '\"' : 'ъ', '\"' : 'Ъ', 'y' : 'ы', 'Y' : 'Ы', '\'' : 'ь', '\'' : 'Ь', 'e' : 'э', 'E' : 'Э', 'yu' : 'ю', 'YU' : 'Ю', 'ya' : 'я', 'YA' : 'Я'};
```

now you can get value of 'a' in russian as

```
replace_list["russian"]['a']
```

In this way you can make your list language specific and extend it to as much languages as you wish

Comment: But it doesn't work with .each for some reason, which is exactly my problem :(

Comment: for a map/object, .each() function works as $.each(map,function(key,value){...});//where map[key] = value;